# How to set multindex for duplicated indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I have a dataframe df with duplicated indices:

```
        a
o_idx
411     x
412     y
412     x
412     z
450     a
450     b
```

I would like to assign multindex to the duplicated rows like:

```
                    a
o_idx    index
411        0        x
412        0        y
412        1        x
412        2        z
450        0        a
450        1        b
```

where the new index is a 0 if it is not a duplicate. If it is a duplicate the new index should be a range of the length of how many times it is duplicated.

I have tried making two dataframes first by trying to get rid of duplicates:

```
a = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
a = a.reset_index()
a.index = np.zeros(len(a.index), dtype = int)
a = a.reset_index()
a = a.set_index(['index', 'o_idx'])
a.index.names = ['index', 'o_idx']
```

then getting the duplicates:

```
b = df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
b = b.reset_index()
b.index = range(len(b.index))
b = b.reset_index()
b = b.set_index(['index', 'o_idx'])
b.index.names = ['index', 'o_idx']
```

Then to concatenate:

```
c = pd.concat([a,b])
```

However this doesn't give me the correct outcome because b is equal to:

```
                    a
o_idx    index
412        0        y
412        1        x
412        2        z
450        3        a
450        4        b
```

So I pretty much have the exact same problem as I did in the beginning. Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `cumcount` then `set_index` back

```
yourdf=df.assign(index=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).set_index('index',append=True)
yourdf
Out[568]: 
             a
o_idx index   
411   0      x
412   0      y
      1      x
      2      z
450   0      a
      1      b
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution set directly to `index`

```
In [1649]: df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
Out[1649]:
       a
411 0  x
412 0  y
    1  x
    2  z
450 0  a
    1  b
```